# Spek parameterized tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, kotlin, spek

I'm trying to write a single test from about 8 hours... The problem is really strange behavior (for me) in Spek. Sometimes it executes, sometimes not. I had an error "Test class cannot have two constructors" without any reason. When i deleted `class DriverTest(val filePath: String, val expectedTextResult: String)` and then put it again, it worked... Anyway, what I'm trying to do is parameterized test:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)
class ChromeDriverConfigurationTest : Spek
({
    class DriverTest(val filePath: String, val expectedTextResult: String)

    given("Chrome Driver") {
        val chromeDriver: ChromeDriver by lazy { setupChromeDriverForTest() }
        afterGroup { deleteChromeDriver(chromeDriver) }

        listOf(
            DriverTest(filePath = "js/js.html", expectedTextResult = "Text from JS!"),
            DriverTest(filePath = "jQuery/jQuery.html", expectedTextResult = "I come from jQuery!"),
            DriverTest(filePath = "angularv1/angularv1.html", expectedTextResult = "Hello from Angular v1!"),
            DriverTest(filePath = "reactJS/index.html", expectedTextResult = "Hello from reactJS!")
        ).forEach { driverTest ->
            println("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB")
            val path = ChromeDriverConfigurationTest::class.java.getResource(driverTest.filePath).path
            chromeDriver.get("file://$path")
            it("should extract test") {
                println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
                val text = chromeDriver.findElement(By.id("test")).text
                assert(text == driverTest.expectedTextResult)
            }

        }
    }
})
```

In this case, I dont see any "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA..", but I see "BBBBBBBB" 4 times. It loks like, `it` section doesn't run. Alright, maybe there is something wrong with `chromeDriver.get`, lets comment it (rest stays same)

```
//val path = ChromeDriverConfigurationTest::class.java.getResource(driverTest.filePath).path
//chromeDriver.get("file://$path")
```

Now I get...

```
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

he? whats going on. Alright, lets move context group inside for each like I saw in many tutorials:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)
class ChromeDriverConfigurationTest : Spek
({
    class DriverTest(val filePath: String, val expectedTextResult: String)

    listOf(
        DriverTest(filePath = "js/js.html", expectedTextResult = "Text from JS!"),
        DriverTest(filePath = "jQuery/jQuery.html", expectedTextResult = "I come from jQuery!"),
        DriverTest(filePath = "angularv1/angularv1.html", expectedTextResult = "Hello from Angular v1!"),
        DriverTest(filePath = "reactJS/index.html", expectedTextResult = "Hello from reactJS!")
    ).forEach { driverTest ->
        given("Chrome Driver") {
            val chromeDriver: ChromeDriver by lazy { setupChromeDriverForTest() }
            afterGroup { deleteChromeDriver(chromeDriver) }
            println("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB")
            val path = ChromeDriverConfigurationTest::class.java.getResource(driverTest.filePath).path
            chromeDriver.get("file://$path")
            it("should extract test") {
                println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
                val text = chromeDriver.findElement(By.id("test")).text
                assert(text == driverTest.expectedTextResult)
            }

        }
    }
})
```

Surprise again:

```
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Okay, just leave these "readability", and make it work... Lets put everything to `it` section.

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)
class ChromeDriverConfigurationTest : Spek
({
class DriverTest(val filePath: String, val expectedTextResult: String)

listOf(
    DriverTest(filePath = "js/js.html", expectedTextResult = "Text from JS!"),
    DriverTest(filePath = "jQuery/jQuery.html", expectedTextResult = "I come from jQuery!"),
    DriverTest(filePath = "angularv1/angularv1.html", expectedTextResult = "Hello from Angular v1!"),
    DriverTest(filePath = "reactJS/index.html", expectedTextResult = "Hello from reactJS!")
).forEach { driverTest ->
    given("Chrome Driver") {
        it("should extract test") {
            val chromeDriver: ChromeDriver by lazy { setupChromeDriverForTest() }
            afterGroup { deleteChromeDriver(chromeDriver) }
            println("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB")
            val path = ChromeDriverConfigurationTest::class.java.getResource(driverTest.filePath).path
            chromeDriver.get("file://$path")
            println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
            val text = chromeDriver.findElement(By.id("test")).text
            assert(text == driverTest.expectedTextResult)
        }

    }
}
})
```

Ohh great it works! But wait a second..., it executes only 1 test, I mean only for first element in list. Hę? Could someone explain me please this behavior? Also maybe you know some other alternatives to Spek? I would write my tests in Kotlin. But with Spek it looks almost impossible

Comment: You can't have duplicate descriptions in Spek 1.x, but this is fixed in 2.x. To fix your problem, just include driverTest in the description. Related issue: https://github.com/spekframework/spek/issues/210

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer, in first example it is in description block (or what do you mean by "description"). Could you show some example with code?

Comment: Do something like: `given("Chrome Driver $driverTest")  { ... }`. The first parameter to `given` is your description.

Comment: It throws NPE on $driverTest

Comment: something wrong with its `toString` method perhaps.

Comment: yeah finally it works, thanks so much :))